# How can I interrupt infinite waiting for networks in systemd boot?

Tags: boot, systemd

I use Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit, desktop version with Unity.

After trying to configure my KVM virtual machine for bridged networking, the `virt-manager` created a corrupt interface configuration `br1`.

When I rebooted (without kernel parameter "quiet splash"), it stopped and showed two alternating messages in red. I can't remember the exact wordings, but both said something about "Waiting for network". one had a timeout of 2 minutes and vanished afterwards, but the other didn't and stayed there infinitely. I could only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and reboot to select `upstart` from the GRUB menu's "advanced options for Ubuntu". That left me without any working keyboard, but this is another story...

**Is there any way to terminate such locked and infinitely waiting boot processes?**

(I managed to remove that corrupt interface configuration and can boot normally again. I am asking whether one can terminate/skip such waiting boot processes in general)

Comment: What have you tried ? remove the br1 and re-configure. If virt-manager / NM can not configure the bridge, file a bug report and manually configure the bridge. If you can not boot from your hard drive you can try booting into recovery mode (no networking) and/or a live USB.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The br1 is removed and I can boot again. That was not the question. Can I abort such infinitely waiting boot processes in general?

Comment: I am not sure, I would file a bug report as the service *should* time out.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Okay, against what should I file it? `systemd` or any networking related package? Because when I booted with `upstart`, it timed out after 2 minutes and continued to boot.

Comment: Hard to know. From what you describe, I would file against systemd and the developers will decide if it is a systemd bug or a vitr-manager or a network bug.

Answer (score -1):

No cause its caused by a bunch of sleeps in the background contained in

```
/etc/init/failsafe.conf
```

If you know what you do, you may replace all these sleeps
with ones having a shorter timeout. As the file contains
(usually) a lot of comments, you should be guided in what you
are doing.

Some background notes: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/839595

Comment: No, that's for `upstart`. Upstart works, I see exactly those messages mentioned in the file you describe and it times out correctly after 2 minutes. My problem is that `systemd` does not have a time out.

Comment: that happens if you shoot before you aim ;-)